# How to cache a mailer view when sending massive email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-3.2, massmail

I need to send massive email,I will use for brackground job Delayed Job, and have to create the email message in 3 languages (de, en, re), How can I cache the view so it doesn't have to create each time I'm calling the the mail method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deliver method is the one that sends the email, so you can do this:

```
def send_emails
  # You can set here the email with attachments and all stuff
  mail = MyMailer.send_message("demo@example.com")
  body = mail.html_part.body

  User.all.each do |u|
    mail.to = u.email
    mail.html_part.body = body.gsub(/user_id/, u.id)
    mail.deliver
  end
end
```

Of course it's better if you set this method for background processing.

Comment: if it's massive than perhaps better use `find_each` and not `all` ?